# ¿Como relaciono tablas en base de datos para satisfacer 3FN?

Tags: base-de-datos, modelorelacional

Estoy tratando de crear una base de datos relacional en 3FN donde tengo:

- Empleados y sus cargos
- Clientes
- Productos
- Cobros
- Pedidos
- Garantías
- Envíos

Pero aún no me ha quedado claro como debo formar las relaciones no importa cuanto contenido vea o lea, o en que otras bases de datos me base como referencia.

El diagrama que tengo es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Uno de los problemas que he tenido es tratar de relacionar los vendedores con los pedidos, pero como ese título se trata de un cargo dentro de la tabla de cargos, no supe cómo hacerlo de manera adecuada entre otras cosas.

Me gustaría saber que puedo cambiar en mi diseño para poder alcanzar 3FN o que errores cometí.

Answer (score 0):

Si usas MER estas tratando de arreglar algo que puede afectar otros niveles de forma normal. Es mejor que lo hagas académicamente. 0FN, 1FN, 2FN. Es más tedioso pero te aseguras de mantener un modelo consistente. Con el nivel computacional de hoy y el modelo tan pequeño no hace falta analizar tanto. No tienes que llegar a la 5FN con 3FN o BCFN creo que sería suficiente.

Por lo demás si tienes preguntas específicas de una relación bien. Pero me parece que es demasiada tarea para un foro de respuestas. Es decir hay un subtotal que claramente te traerá in con sistencias.